# QGIS N:M relations - possibility to edit multiple features?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, editing, many-to-many, relation

I have a working QGIS project with multiple relations and all is well until I try the Toggle multi edit mode for N:M relations. I'm working with QGIS 3.10+ (3.14.16) and Windows  and PostGIS.

Is it even possible to edit multiple features with N:M relation and, if it is, what buttons should I push to activate this?

[image: Normal attribute form view with one N:M relation]

[image: If I want to edit multiple features, it allows me to edit only 1:N relations but not N:M relations]

When in multi edit mode the N:M relations are hidden and not shown. I thought I managed to do this once, but don't know what buttons I pushed and now I start to think I was imagining things.

If you need better example I can draft one in English, but I have been following the documentation here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#editing-multiple-fields

I can also contribute to the documentation on this if needed.

Comment: And same problem when splitting an object: the N:M values are not inherited to the new feature.

Comment: I don't think you can. First, realize that the m:n form belong to another table, it's just embed inside the "main" table's form, filtered by the current feature. That's why it disappears once you enter in multi-edit mode. Regarding the  split features, it also expected. You need to recreate the relations to the new features.

Comment: @AlexandreNeto thank you so much for the answer! Plan B then... this could be done with SQL I think.  And if we get funding, we could check if there is a way to handle splitting and update the inherited information accordingly. This feature is relevant for e.g. land use planning where you have multiple spatial features with the same definition, theme or documents (coming from many-to-many relations). When you have multiple features without definitions, it would be helpfull to fill out them by selecting and updating.